# HDTV resolution issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, resolution

Fresh ubuntu install, Nvidia drivers for 9600GTOC hooked up to a 26" Polaroid  HDTV Via DVI - HDMI cable. The native resolution looks fine other than it goes out silghtly past the edge of my screen, how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is [overscan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan).

I had this problem with our last TV which was essentially just fixed with some messing around with the picture settings in the TV's menu.

Also just check (in `nvidia-settings`) that your resolution and refresh rates are what the TV's native rates are (look online or in the manual).