# 1080p on TV not working

Tags: display

I am trying to connect my laptop (Samsung Series 5 Ultrabook) to my TV (Toshiba WLT66/67 Series) and get it to output to the TV at 1080i (so basically 1920x1080) through HDMI

The issue I have is that in 'Displays' the highest resolution that it gives the monitor is 1280x768, however I know that the TV can output at 1920x1080 at 30Hz as when I use Windows 7 it allows me to do this.

I looked around and found that I could use xrandr to try and get his resolution, however when I do:

```
cvt 1920 1080 30
    # 1920x1080 29.95 Hz (CVT) hsync: 33.01 kHz; pclk: 79.75 MHz
    Modeline "1920x1080_30.00"   79.75  1920 1976 2168 2416  1080 1083 1088 1102 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_30.00"   79.75  1920 1976 2168 2416  1080 1083 1088 1102 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1920x1080_30.00

xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080_30.00
```

My TV screen just remains blank :( Any help? (if you need any more information please ask)

Comment: What is the graphic card / chipset in your laptop? did you try installing some restricted driver?

Answer (score 1):

As recommend reading this question/answer: [HDMI/VGA connection cuts borders of screen or creates blurry text](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80324/hdmi-video-connection-cuts-top-and-bottom-borders-of-screen) for some additional information but the problem might be the actual the configuration for the TV. What I mean with this as for example, you are saying you can have 1920 with a 30 refresh rate. Check `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` so that the Horizontal/Vertical sync is at least 30. In my case it is 50/60.

Another way is to not jump directly to 1920 but rather go slowly towards it. Jump to the next higher resolution. Then the next. At least until you get to 1920. I would recommend using 1680x1050 because many TVs in Ubuntu that mention 1920 work better on 1680. If you had an Nvidia, some of the options you could do with the Nvidia Settings would help.

There are also some TVs that have an option to automatically correct the resolution. You could also try that.